# Fragment replacing giving NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

So i have a Main Activity that has by default the MainPage Fragment , When navigating to LoginPage Fragment using Navigation Drawer and promoting a valid username and password for Parse and then clicking a button to return to the MainPage Fragment ;gives this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

this following code when clicking the Button to submit values:

```
MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, mainPage);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

So it gives me an Error on these lines of codes that it ran before when first launching the MainPage Fragment:

```
**(Gives Error Here)**query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           **(Gives Error Here)**  for (ParseObject Obj1 : objects) {
                names.add(Obj1.get("Name").toString());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.items, names);
            ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainPageListView);
            listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: But why it's null ? And i tried to check if it was null using if statement , but it wasn't .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Solved by adding this line in the main fragment page :

```
View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragmentMain,container,false);
```

Changed the current return to : `return view;`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a Fragment by tag.

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("stringtag");
```

But you have to define it when you call the replace:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, mainPage, "stringtag");
```